# Understanding a TCP reset

Tags: tcp, reset, wireshark, packets

I've been tasked with looking into a connection problem from between a client and web server. I have a Wireshark capture which I've looked at but don't fully understand - my background is in development mainly and networking is a little out of my depth.

The conversation looks like this:

Frame #1: client sends 66 bytes SYN via TCP at 16:17:13
Frame #5: client re-transmits 66 bytes SYN via TCP at 16:17:16
Frame #6: client re-transmits 62 bytes SYN via TCP at 16:17:22
Frame #13: server sends RST via TCP at 16:18:20.

What strikes me as odd is the really short time between re-transmission attempts but I'm not knowledgeable enough to know if this is suspicious. The problem is intermittent when attempting to make a HTTP request to the server on port 80.

My hunch is that the user's bespoke software is sending bad/out-of-ordered packets but am unable to prove this.

Due to data protection I'm unable to submit the capture file, unforunately.

I hope one of you network guys can help.

Comment: A couple of questions here...Where are you capturing the traffic (e.g., client-side)? Are all of the packets listed as Frames 1, 5, and 6 SYN packets? Also, do you have access to the web server logs? Depending on what lies between the client and web server, a few seconds between re-tries could actually be a pretty long time.

Comment: The capture was done on the client side. Frame 1,5 and 6 are indeed SYN packets. I do have access to the Apache logs - the capture onnly has the LAN IP so I'll have to request to external-facing IP to be of any use in the logs.

Comment: The times between SYNs are normal. First 3 then 6 seconds. Next one would have been 12. The server is probably overloaded, and therefore its backlog queue is full, so it is ignoring incoming connection requests, then finally rejecting one.  Nothing bespoke happening here.

Comment: If the server responds with a RST flag, would that be recorded in the Apache logs or somewhere else?

Comment: It wouldn't be recorded anywhere except your packet sniff. The Apache server wouldn't even know about it.

Comment: One other thought might be to run a capture on the server side to verify that the client's requests are getting to the server intact...in case there is something between the server and client that is causing confusion from the server's perspective.